# Cycles of Possible Duplicate question

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, close-reasons

What happens if a set of questions are all marked possible duplicate in such a way the questions form a cycle? Is this taken care of on SO?

Example: A set of 3 questions where each question is closed by saying the other two are possible duplicates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cycles of Possible Duplicate question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276739/cycles-of-possible-duplicate-question)

Comment: Well, there you have a self loop cycle. The simplest of examples.

Comment: @gunr2171 I see what you didn't do there.

Comment: To be fair, I just wrote the comment as a joke, I didn't vote. But I don't think the system would allow that sort of behavior. We would have to test this anyways.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54024/prevent-circular-close-as-exact-duplicate-loop

Comment: I am pretty sure I've been able to VTC question B as duplicate of question A when there were open votes on A to close it as a duplicate of B.

Comment: If you want to experiment, here's 3 candidates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863465/jshint-function-is-defined-but-never-used-or-how-to-declare-a-function, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607289/prevent-jshint-warning-that-functionname-is-defined-but-never-used and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763987/jshint-myfunction-is-defined-but-never-used

Comment: @gunr2171 If you actually try to close it  as a self-duplicate, you'll get **Questions can not be duplicates of themselves**  -- and to that I say Bah! Humbug!? Of course they are, by definition!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The system won't let you do it; it will recognize the cycle and prevent the closure that would create it.

That said, there have been a few bugs with this in the past, resulting in some cycles being created.  If you actually find one, just flag it and explain the problem and a mod will handle the situation.